# Generate Sequence Number in Edittext Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to generate sequence number in EditText when I press enter button.
Detail explanation :
Everytime I want to write a character for the first time in edittext should begin with this string --> "1."
And after I finish write the sentence and press enter button (new line), the next sentence should begin with the next sequence number

For example :
When I write in edittext for the first time like this

> this is the first sentence

, it should be like this

> 1.) this is the first sentence

And then when I press enter button to write the next sentence like this

> this is the second sentences

it should be like this

> 2.) this is the second sentences

I try to write the code, but there was an unexpected result when I try to write the first character in EditText
This is my whole code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText mET;

    public int getCurrentCursorLine(EditText editText)
    {    
        int selectionStart = Selection.getSelectionStart(editText.getText());
        Layout layout = editText.getLayout();

        if (!(selectionStart == -1)) {
            return layout.getLineForOffset(selectionStart);
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mET.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int startCursor = 0;
                    startCursor = mET.getSelectionStart();


                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {

                        mET.getText().insert(startCursor, "\n" + String.valueOf(getCurrentCursorLine(mET)+2) + ".) ");

                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mEditText);

        Editable text = mET.getText();
        text.insert(mET.getSelectionStart(), "1.) ");

        mET.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

That's my whole code guys..
By using my code above, the result was become like this :

> 1.) this is the first sentence
>   2.)
>   3.) this is the second sentences
>   4.)
>   5.) this is the third sentences

The question is, why it was executed twice?

And, when I pressed enter button to insert a new line in the line 2 for example, the result was become like this :

> 1.) this is the first sentence
>   2.) this is the second sentences
>   3.)
>   4.)
>   3.) this is the second sentences
>   4.)
>   5.) this is the third sentences

I want to update the whole number when I insert a new line in the random line.
now I need your help to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to remove `\n` from the below line

```
mET.getText().insert(startCursor, "\n" + String.valueOf(getCurrentCursorLine(mET)+2) + ".) ");
```

because the enter from the keyboard already add the new line. after that you again puts another new line.

So, remove `"\n" +` from that line .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your advice but it didn't work. '\n' is needed because when I pressed 'enter' key, the startCursor was not in the new line. So, if we remove '\n', that line was still executed twice but without new line.

Answer (score 0):

You might have found the answer already or maybe not. But I believe that the problem is that you set "mET" to "onKey" which I believe is both doing the "onKeyDown" AND "onKeyUp". So that's maybe why it does the action twice because you are pressing and releasing the enter/d-pad center key.

So really all you need to do is add before

```
...keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER...
```

Add this before...

```
...event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && ...
```

Then add the rest.